# Can the Visual Studio Code Remote - Container extension connect to a windows container?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I run the command in VS code, my container appears in the list, and it attempts to connect, but I get an error code saying "The user name or password is incorrect." My container is exactly the one built from this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/advanced-build-tools-container?view=vs-2017

Is the extension able to connect to a windows container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/445

The answer is clearly no for now.